# Pyqt close window runs but doesn't work

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a function which takes care of the closing of my application. But somehow the ..quit() doesn't close the window. It doesn't stuck into an infinity loop or something like that.

```
def onExit():
    QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit
    sys.exit(app)
    shutdown = 1
    #set the shutdown var to the child process
    parent.send(shutdown)
    logProc.join()
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.exit()
```

solved this